# \lstinline break at punctuation

Tags: listings, line-breaking, inline

I need listing package (`\usepackage{listing}`) to break at punctuation

```
namespace::subnamespace::class
           ^             ^
```

at either these two locations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This breaks at `::`, but puts it `::` in the new line.

```
\lstset{literate={::}{::}{2\discretionary{}{}{}}}
```

This leaves a hyphenated `::` in the old line, but the spacing is terrible.

```
\lstset{literate={::}{}{0\discretionary{::}{}{::}}}
```

This monster fixes the spacing:

```
\def\colonspace{\hspace{0.2em}}%
\lstset{literate={::}{}{0\discretionary{\mbox{:\colonspace:}}{}{\mbox{\colonspace:\colonspace:\colonspace}}}}
```

Btw, you can also break in the middle of `::` ;-)

```
\lstset{literate={::}{}{0\discretionary{:}{:}{::}}}
```

Comment: For punctuation in general does that mean I will have to define them one by one?

Comment: At least I don't know a better way.