# Problem with 'é' character in listings

Tags: listings, unicode

I have this **MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  extendedchars=true,
  postbreak=\space, breakindent=5pt, breaklines,
  literate={à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1,
}


\begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}
  //...
  API api = new API(url);
  CultureIntermediaire cultureIntermediaire = resultat.getCultureIntermediaire();

  //On affiche le nom de la méthode de travail du sol la plus érosive

 \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result**
[image]

I have a problem : the "é" character is alone

Is there a way to tell listing to wrap when it find a point and not only a space. I want to get something like this :

```
CultureIntermediaire cultureIntermediaire = resultat.
                                          getCultureIntermediaire();
```

Comment: Unfortunately `listings` doesn't really support UTF-8 characters in comments. Maybe using `listingsutf8` can help; however it requires the listing is in a separate file and is input with `\lstinputlisting`.

Comment: I think that's the only solution I have. The problem is that I will have many file of code and each file will contain only about 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the line break at period, you can do as the follow:

```
literate= {.}{}{1\discretionary{.}{}{.}},
```

Which does the line break at the `.`, however, it doesn't do it so beautifully. To tweak the output, have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97695/22492) answer. This part of the answer tells you something: `literate` is some sort of hack to put unicode characters. Another solution could be to escape as [Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) suggests in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24544/22492) answer.

```
\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  extendedchars=true,
  postbreak=\space, breakindent=5pt, breaklines,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}, % I'm new here!
  literate= {.}{}{1\discretionary{.}{}{.}}, % So am I
}
```

with `\usepackage{listingsutf8}` as was suggested in the comment by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg). You then have to replace your comment with the following

```
// %*On affiche le nom de la méthode de travail du sol la plus érosive!*)
```

that renders to

[image]

P.S. It is a good practice to have your code in a separate file and add it to listings with `lstinputlisting`. This not only makes the project more organizable, but also prevents some of the headaches related to listings. (for example, check the code in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91302/22492) answer to see how to use that command).

Comment: When I escape my comment, the comment are no longer considered as comment and are printed in black (not in green in my case).

Comment: What comes between escape characters are considered as latex code and you can use latex commands to colorize escaped comments (`\textcolor{green}{your comment}`. Unescaped comments would be fine btw). I know this is an inconvenience but as egreg mentioned, listings is not very friendly with utf8. You may consider minted package but in all honesty, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @user230137 If you can work with `latin1` encoding (which in my case works, I just need to change the encoding in the text editor and use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`), then you will see that many of those problems go away (e.g., accents are supported by default, without `literate`).

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that with a comment was enough, but I think this deserves an answer. Since is something I learned rather late (a few weeks ago).

`listings` is much more friendly if you use `latin1` as input encoding. For instance, accents work without `literate`, that is, out of the box (and also [non-breaking spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185131/21930)).

What could go wrong? I don't know. What are the downsides/upsides of `latin1`? I don't know. Feel free to edit in case you know.

Remember to *save* the document with `latin1` encoding.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset%
 {frame = tb,
  language = Java,
  aboveskip = 3mm,
  belowskip = 3mm,
  showstringspaces = false,
  columns = flexible,
  basicstyle = {\small\ttfamily},
  numbers = none,
  breaklines = true,
  breakatwhitespace = true,
  tabsize = 3,
  extendedchars = true,
  postbreak = \space, breakindent = 5pt, breaklines,}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
 //...
 API api = new API(url);
 CultureIntermediaire cultureIntermediaire = resultat.getCultureIntermediaire();

 //On affiche le nom de la méthode de travail du sol la plus érosive
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

---

As commented by @Pouya, in particular, french (e.g., œ, æ) is not fully supported (here is the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)). However, it seems that `latin9` (ISO-8859-15) does fully support it, so you may need to use it. Is it better? Again, I don't know. It would be great to have a complete reference about pros and cons of different encodings.

Comment: I said `latin1` because since I discovered it, I use it when I have problems (is the one used in the liked question). Is the best choice? Again: I don't know. May be other encodings work as well, and even better. Feel free to add extra info ;)

Comment: I think (OP can correct me if I'm wrong) the comments are going to be in French and French is not fully supported by latin1. For example, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) WikipediA article suggests that `œ` is not actually part of latin1 encoding. Now, granted that I don't know French, there is a chance that those characters are rarely used and latin1 may work properly. Please note that I'm not questioning the validity of your answer, it's just a side note that one might take into consideration. Cheers `:)`.